# Cant locate a SQL Server backup job that is running and failing

Tags: sql-server

There is a backup job that is running for master and msdb which is trying to use Azure blob storage as the backup location and I dont know where it's configured.

I need to delete this job but cannot find it anywhere. The only reason I know its running is because it's failing and littering up the SQL logs. There are no maintenance plans or scheduled jobs running any backups. I am using Azure Recovery Vault with VM agent tools to do our backups and those are all working as expected.

At some point someone must of set up a job, script, or something that keeps trying to take these backups but for the life of me I cannot find where/how it's running. Are there any recommended places (queries, DMVs. etc) I can look to locate where/what is running this?

What I know:

- It tries daily to run and continues to try for a few hours
- There are no SQL Agent Jobs
- There are no maintenance plans
- It gets logged to the SQL logs
- It gets logged to windows event viewer under 'Windows Logs > Application'

[image]

Comment: It's running as NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT.  It must be an agent job owned by an admin.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I thought this as well, there are no jobs under 'SQL Agent > Jobs' that perform a back up.

Comment: And you are a sysadmin?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, also a full admin on the machine.

Comment: There may be software that is creating the job, running it and deleting it immediately. Check also all the job steps of each job you have, perhaps you only checked the first job step.

Comment: Maybe this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Jeff You got it, that's was exactly what it was! I went in and disabled the managed backups and the logs and so far the logs are clean. Thanks!

Comment: @mluker - glad that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from Jeff, the solution was disabling the Azure Managed Backups that had previously been configured.